# Making request(s) after getting an object from first request

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2, rx-android

I am new to Rx and need help with understanding it. I am using TMDB to get data. Now it returns me a Json Object which contains a List of movie ids. I want to be able to send request(s) for ids in this list.

Lets say my first request is searchFor(String query), which gives me a Object which contains a response field which has a List of movies.
My second request is getDetails(String id), which is the final data I wish to show.

I have a made a `Single<MovieResponse> searchFor(String query)`, and `Single<MovieDetail> getDetails(String id)`.

The problem is I want to keep it reactive and make the 2nd request(getDetails) immediately as I receive data from the 1st request.

I was thinking of something like FlatMap.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I could chain the operators to achieve what I wanted.
I did,

```
Single.subscribeOn(...)
    .observeOn(...)
    .map(...)      // return the arraylist in the object
    .flatmap(...)  // return observable for that arraylist
    .flatmap(...)  // return (n) observables for the elements of arraylist
```

Comment: Use `flattenAsObservable` instead

Comment: Will that replace both the flatmaps?

Comment: `Single.flatMap` returns another `Single`. so you pretty much have no choice but to use either `flattenAsObservable` or `flatMapObservable` instead.